# Upload image to server from Android

Tags: php, android, apache

I developed an application for upload image from Android on XAMPP server with PHP file. In Android the application runs perfect and image appears as uploaded and no errors appears but when I enter the server there is nothing. Here is my Android code and my PHP code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.androiddownloadmanagerdemo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <activity android:name=".AdvanceFileUpload"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.androiddownloadmanagerdemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner       "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-   android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- core:3.2.0'
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.androiddownloadmanagerdemo;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_GALLERY = 200;

TextView file_name;
String file_path=null;
Button upload;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button upload_file=findViewById(R.id.upload_file);
    upload_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //check permission greater than equal to marshmeellow we used run time permission
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
                if(checkPermission()){
                    filePicker();
                }
                else{
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }
            else{
                filePicker();
            }
        }
    });

    progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progress);
    upload=findViewById(R.id.upload);
    file_name=findViewById(R.id.filename);

    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(file_path!=null){
                UploadFile();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Select File First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


    Button advacneUpload=findViewById(R.id.advanceupload);
    advacneUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdvanceFileUpload.class));
        }
    });



}

private void UploadFile() {
    UploadTask uploadTask=new UploadTask();
    uploadTask.execute(new String[]{file_path});
}


private void filePicker(){

    //.Now Permission Working
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Picker Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Let's Pick File
    Intent opengallery=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    opengallery.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(opengallery,REQUEST_GALLERY);
}



private void requestPermission(){
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Give Permission to Upload File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission(){
    int result= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if(result== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        String filePath=getRealPathFromUri(data.getData(),MainActivity.this);
        Log.d("File Path : "," "+filePath);
        //now we will upload the file
        //lets import okhttp first
        this.file_path=filePath;

        File file=new File(filePath);
        file_name.setText(file.getName());

    }
}

public String getRealPathFromUri(Uri uri,Activity activity){
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor=activity.getContentResolver().query(uri,proj,null,null,null);
    if(cursor==null){
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    else{
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int id=cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(id);
    }
}


public class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        if(uploadFile(strings[0])){
            return "true";
        }
        else{
            return "failed";
        }
    }

    private boolean uploadFile(String path){
        File file=new File(path);
        try{
            RequestBody requestBody=new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("files",file.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file))
                    .addFormDataPart("some_key","some_value")
                    .addFormDataPart("submit","submit")
                    .build();

            Request request=new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://"myIPv4adress"/projects/upload.php/")
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                }
            });
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$target="uploads/".basename($_FILES['files']['name']);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'],$target)){
  echo "uploaded";
}
else{
echo "failed";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello again, [Andreea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18645144/andreea) ... Why you are creating another account?

Comment: I don’t have permissions to edit post and I had to wait 3 days

Comment: `getRealPathFromUri` hehe again, and again  ... well there is no path (or at least - there may be no path) ... 99% of `getRealPathFromUri` implementation is wrong... get stream from uri, save stream as local file,  and then use it's path

Comment: more over you are using another thread twice - which doesn't make sens ... once using `AsyncTask` and second one using `Call.enqueue`

Comment: I didn't find any relevant information on how to do everything you said above

Answer (score 0):

if you can use postman upload image to your php server, you can get client code from postman [Generating client code](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32610853)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this than first convert image into base64 string and than convert it into image on your backend side.

Maybe it will helpful

Comment: there is no need for base64